# MySQL: Trying query for client information only if that client has both a savings and checking account

Tags: mysql

The two tables below are examples:

```
create table client (gid bigint(3), cid bigint(3));
insert into client values (0, 1);
insert into client values (1, 2);
insert into client values (2, 3);

create table balance(gid bigint(3), bid bigint(3)), type varchar(10));
insert into balance values (0, 1, 'checking');
insert into balance values (1, 2, 'savings');
insert into balance values (2, 3, 'checking');
insert into balance values (2, 4, 'savings');
insert into balance values (2, 5, 'checking');
```

Client table contains a general account and client id. The balance table contains a general account and balance id with an account type. For each general id, there can be many clients, and for each general id there can be many balances.

What I am suppose to figure out is how to write a single select statement that joins the two tables into one, and then return the only the client ids that have both a checking and savings account.

| gid | cid | bid | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | checking |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | savings |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | checking |

I figured out how to join the tables with the applicable format using:

```
SELECT Client_Account.General_Account_General_ID,
    Client_ID,
    Balance_Account_ID,
    Account_Type 
    FROM Client_Account 
    INNER JOIN Balance_Account 
    ON Client_Account.General_Account_General_ID 
    = Balance_Account.General_Account_General_ID
```

I know that my question is not written very well, but I will try to edit as many times as possible to clarify. Thank you for the time and consideration.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the meaning of `gid`, `cid` and `bid`?

Comment: @Progman, general id, client id, balance id. The database and tables are more complex than what is put above. However, the extra details should be irrelevant in terms of figuring out if this is possible. I'm pretty sure this is possible, it's just out of my scope of knowledge.

Comment: @Program, I have made an edit so that my question should be easier to understand. The table represents what I need, but I cannot query based on a given value for gid.

Comment: @NavrajBains Does the `balance` table have multiple `checking` or `savings` entries for a given `gid` or will there be always be at most one `checking` and/or `savings` entry?

Comment: @Progman, The balance table can only every have one type according to the specifications.

Comment: @NavrajBains Please [edit] your question to include a more detailde/extended example with more rows in the tables and the result table you have, which shows the various scenarios you have you need to cover.

Comment: @NavrajBains You said that the `balance` table can only have one row for a give `type` and `gid`, but your example table contains the combination `gid=2` and `type=checking` twice. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find `gid` values with two entries in the `balance` table. The query can look like this:

```
SELECT
    gid
FROM
    balance
GROUP BY
    gid
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This will generate the following result:

```
+------+
| gid  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```

Use this query in another query to get the rows you want based on these found `gid` values like this:

```
SELECT
    b.gid,
    c.cid,
    b.bid,
    b.type
FROM
    balance b
JOIN
    client c ON b.gid = c.gid
WHERE
    b.gid IN (SELECT
                  gid
              FROM
                  balance
              GROUP BY
                  gid
              HAVING
                  COUNT(*) = 2);
```

This will generate the following result:

```
+------+------+------+----------+
| gid  | cid  | bid  | type     |
+------+------+------+----------+
|    2 |    3 |    3 | checking |
|    2 |    3 |    4 | savings  |
+------+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Works for the specific case but does not scale if a client has more than one checking or savings account.

Comment: In which way does it not scale or what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try inner query with EXISTS inside of WHERE statement as so:

```
SELECT *
    FROM client
    INNER JOIN balance b1
    ON client.gid = b1.gid
    WHERE EXISTS(
       SELECT '' FROM balance b2 
       WHERE b2.gid = b1.gid AND b2.cid != b1.cid AND b2.type != b1.type LIMIT 1);
```

Subquery just look inside of the same table for rows with same gid but difference cid and type. If found, the row will be in the result set.

But I am not sure about the results as I do not fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way the specifications where written and my interpretation. The case is that the return does not need to be a client with both a savings and checking, but either a checking or savings. The solution given is:

```
SELECT Client_Account.General_Account_General_ID,
    Client_ID,
    Balance_Account_ID,
    Account_Type 
    FROM Client_Account 
    INNER JOIN Balance_Account 
    ON Client_Account.General_Account_General_ID 
    = Balance_Account.General_Account_General_ID 
    WHERE Balance_Account.Type = "checking" 
    OR Balance_Account.Type = "savings"
```

In this case, not clarifying the instructions lead to me creation my own errors.

Comment: So actually you are not answering your own question. Can you edit the question ?